# ¿Cómo cambiar las posiciones de un array en un orden determinado en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Muy buenas tardes, mi siguiente inquietud es como realizar un **array** dinámico que cambie sus valores internos en un orden especifico para un **fixture** deportivo.

```
function GenerarFixture(){
//llenar array para ejemplo
var Equipos = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i <4; i++) {

    Equipos[i] = i;     
}
//4 equipos
if(true)
{
    document.write("<table class='table'>");
        //fecha 2
        document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<th scope='col'>Fecha ","1"," </th>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'>");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[0]," VS ", Equipos[1],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'>");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[3]," VS ", Equipos[2],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
        //fecha 2
        document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<th scope='col'>Fecha ","2"," </th>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'>");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[0]," VS ", Equipos[2],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'>");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[1]," VS ", Equipos[3],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
        //fecha 3
        document.write("<tr>");
            document.write("<th scope='col'>Fecha ","3"," </th>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'>");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[0]," VS ", Equipos[3],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");

        document.write("<tr scope='row'> ");
            document.write("<td>",Equipos[2]," VS ", Equipos[1],"</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");


    document.write("</table>");         
}

}
```

**Descripción:** 
El anterior código fue una solución que estaba planteando, pero la idea es realizarlo con un ciclo for para que sea mas dinámico y evitar escribir muchas lineas de código.

**Referencias** 
Para entender algunos conceptos de lógica sobre el ejercicio visitar la  siguiente publicación : https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_todos_contra_todos

Comment: Bienvenido/a a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para que aprendas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio. También comentar que difícilmente encontrarás aquí quien esté dispuesto a hacer tu tarea escolar completa. Hay muchos en capacidad y dispuestos a ayudar, pero es mejor que lo intentes tu primero y vengas con preguntas puntuales sobre las dudas que tengas al hacer ese ejercicio. Para más información te invito a leer [ask]. Un saludo.